# Partition delete on logical standby

Tags: oracle, database-administration, database-replication

I am deleting a few records from the partition on physical DB as below

```
DELETE FROM  t_orders partition(SYS_P607707) where category = 'OTC';
```

to confirm the changes on logical standby I issued the below statement .

```
select COUNT(*) from t_orders partition(SYS_P607707)  where category = 'OTC';
```

I am getting the error partition does not exist but when I verified the data it actually got deleted from logical standby.
My question is how the counts are matching when the specified partition in logical DB is not matching with the physical DB? Is this the right way to perform the deletes in order to ensure the consistency between physical and logical DB.? Please advise.

```
ORA-02149: Specified partition does not exist 
02149. 00000 -  "Specified partition does not exist %s"
*Cause:    Partition not found for the object.
```